# Using Ruby StringIO's gets method

Tags: ruby

If I run the following code:

```
require 'stringio'
chunked_data = StringIO.new("7\r\nHello, \r\n6\r\nworld!\r\n0\r\n")
data = ""
until chunked_data.eof?
  if chunk_head = chunked_data.gets("\r\n")
    print chunk_head
    if chunk = chunked_data.read(chunk_head.to_i)
      print chunk
      data << chunk
    end
  end
end
```

I get this output:

```
7
Hello, 
6
world!
0
```

[According to the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-gets), the `gets` method takes a separator and returns the next line based on that separator. If I replace the `\r\n` in the string and separator with `.`, then the separator functionality seems to no longer work and I get this:

```
7.Hello, .6.world!.0.
```

What's going on?

Comment: Tested your code and I get the same result for both `\r\n` and `.`. The method does not remove the separator from the string, if that is what confuses you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what's actually going on, let's replace `print` with a more explicit output:

```
require 'stringio'

def parse(chunked_data, separator)
  data = ""
  until chunked_data.eof?
    if chunk_head = chunked_data.gets(separator)
      puts "chunk_head: #{chunk_head.inspect}"
      if chunk = chunked_data.read(chunk_head.to_i)
        puts "     chunk: #{chunk.inspect}"
        data << chunk
      end
    end
  end
  data
end

result = parse(StringIO.new("7\r\nHello, \r\n6\r\nworld!\r\n0\r\n"), "\r\n")
puts "    result: #{result.inspect}"
```

Output:

```
chunk_head: "7\r\n"
     chunk: "Hello, "
chunk_head: "\r\n"
     chunk: ""
chunk_head: "6\r\n"
     chunk: "world!"
chunk_head: "\r\n"
     chunk: ""
chunk_head: "0\r\n"
     chunk: ""
```

Now with a `.`:

```
result = parse(StringIO.new("7.Hello, .6.world!.0."), ".")
puts "    result: #{result.inspect}"
```

Output:

```
chunk_head: "7."
     chunk: "Hello, "
chunk_head: "."
     chunk: ""
chunk_head: "6."
     chunk: "world!"
chunk_head: "."
     chunk: ""
chunk_head: "0."
     chunk: ""
    result: "Hello, world!"
```

As you can see, it works either way and the result is identical.

Although the result is correct, there seems to be a bug in your code: you don't read the separator after `chunk`. This can be fixed by adding a `chunked_data.gets(separator)` or `chunked_data.read(separator.bytesize)`
after the `if/end` block:

```
def parse(chunked_data, separator)
  data = ""
  until chunked_data.eof?
    if chunk_head = chunked_data.gets(separator)
      puts "chunk_head: #{chunk_head.inspect}"
      if chunk = chunked_data.read(chunk_head.to_i)
        puts "     chunk: #{chunk.inspect}"
        data << chunk
      end
      chunked_data.read(separator.bytesize)
    end
  end
  data
end

result = parse(StringIO.new("7.Hello, .6.world!.0."), ".")
puts "    result: #{result.inspect}"
```

Output:

```
chunk_head: "7."
     chunk: "Hello, "
chunk_head: "6."
     chunk: "world!"
chunk_head: "0."
     chunk: ""
    result: "Hello, world!"
```

That looks better.